# Combining two integers to make a time

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to use a compare function to compare to time codes. The time codes are created in the shell by doing compare(1,3,6,4). It needs to be output as 1:03 and 6:04 and I'm not sure how to convert these 4 integers into time signatures. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by a 'certain time' here? To print? To do calculations with? What is the underlying use case you are trying to solve?

Comment: If you just want to format the numbers for output, you are asking a *how do I format two numbers* question, for example.

Comment: No it doesn't need to have am pm. I just want to convert the two integers into a time format.

Comment: Then you don't need any module `print("{:02}:{:02}".format(a,b))`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `datetime` module

```
>>> from datetime import time
>>> a, b = 11, 39
>>> dt = time(11, 39)
>>> dt.strftime('%H:%M')
'11:39'
```

Comment: Yet this is overkill if all they wanted to do was format two integers.. `'{:d}:{:02d}'.format(a, b)`. And if they wanted to do *time delta calculations*, then the `datetime.time` object is the wrong type. There's a reason I closed the question as unclear. :-)

Comment: Erm... pretty sure you can't mix `%` templating and `str.format` like that.  But I get what you're saying :)

Comment: What mixing? :-P (You never saw that).